# Unable to assign the content of a label

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I have a weird bug where assigning the content of a label will not work with a string variable. E.g.

```
usernameLabel.Content = userName;
```

Instead of the content changing to the string it is just blank. I have checked that the string userName contains characters since i am able to produce a messagebox that displays the username for instance "Dave".

```
MessageBox.Show(userName);
```

Here's a [link](http://gyazo.com/b53c298e05eaafa5e1f0e07d9042787a) to a screenshot.

thanks guys!

The edit: 
in my log in page the string Username is set:

```
public static string Username
        {
            get { return username; }
            set { username = value; }
        }
```

And is retrieved in the main window

```
private static string userName
        {
            get { return Launcher.Username; }
        }
```

This correctly retrieves the string since i can produce a messagebox showing the string. The code label is changed at:

```
public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            // Various Code... 
            usernameLabel.Content = userName;
        }
```

My test using messagebox is simply put within a random button's click event.
And the XAML behind the label:

```
<Label x:Name="usernameLabel" Content="username" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="72" Height="20" FontFamily="Calibri" Foreground="White" FontSize="14" Background="Black" Margin="187,3,0,0" Padding="5,0"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to make the label display text?
If so, try `usernameLabel.Text = userName;` instead.

Edit: Things to consider

- Is there any code that deletes the contents of `userName` before it is returned to the next form?
- Did you correctly use variable names? e.g. `username` is not `userName`
- Are you returning the correct variable?

Comment: in wpf Label has no definition for Text, instead Content is used

Comment: I was able to replicate your code and it worked fine. Could you edit your question to include the whole method?

Comment: Okay so i don't know how to format code in comments. Is a pastebin okay for you?

Comment: Yes, the code that you posted should work. Label is a ContentControl and you can set the Content property to a string. As written and shown [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.content%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). This must be something else, more from the code would be awesome. Maybe some style hiding/making the text invisible? Does it work if you set it from XAML? `<Label>This is the content</Label>`

Comment: For testing purposes, try adding the `usernameLabel.Content = userName;` line in the same method where the messagebox is called (button).

Comment: @Gus there is no code that deletes the content of the label nor the string. I stuck the code to set the label contents to userName within a buttons click event and it successfully changed.. Which makes me think the location within public MainWindow is incorrect.. however if i change to usernameLabel.Content = "foo" or even to = foo where foo = string foo = "foo" the labels content is succesfully changed on startup. I really am lost...

Comment: You should track the `username` variable by stepping-into (F8) and see where and when `username` changes.

Comment: In the watch it says the Value is "Unable to evaluate the espression" however it does have a value since i can produce a message box and correctly change the label's content within a buttons click event

Comment: @Gus okay i've figured the "problem".. the code is running at startup, before i have set the value of username during login process. Therefore is null.